# Trying to replace <title> tags with an image friendly replacement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on further developing the liquid slider and am trying to replace the text within the   tags (or the tags completely, given that the title tags only seem to be for text)

Anyway.. I'd like to find a way to possibly reference two different images, for each of the navigational components, without having them repeated within the slider div's.

Looking through the "jquery.liquid-slider-custom.min" file, I found that it's linked by the .title class through this code:

```
includeTitle:true,panelTitleSelector:".title",dynamicTabsAlign:"left",
dynamicTabsPosition:"top",navElementTag:"div",firstPanelToLoad:1
```

Any insight?

Here's a link to the page.

http://www.newechelonart.com/test/slider1/lstest.html

Comment: Do note that the [`<title>`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/title) element is far and away not the same as any element with a `title` class on it.

Comment: @ajp15243 I understand that. The only way I could figure out to not have the text repeated within the nav is to use the <title> tag, as a <h1> or <h2> would be displayed within the slider divs.

The jquery lists the .title class as the one to pull information from and use for navigational information.. It just so happens that the <title class="title"> </title> was the only viable combination, given the current code structure in "jquery.liquid-slider-custom.min"

Thanks much for your response!

Comment: The `<title>` element is an element that should only be used once in the `<head>` element to indicate what your page title is. It should not be used as content markup inside `<body>`.  If it happened to work for you, it's because browsers are forgiving, not because it's correct or can/should be used that way.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reference the tags individually, why not just add an ID attribute to them?

Comment: I have tried... I suppose it's a matter of figuring out exactly what I need to switch to make that reference happen (specifically in the "jquery.liquid-slider-custom.min" file)

Comment: This should remove and replace your navigation with whatever you want: `document.getElementsByClassName("tab1").item(0).innerHTML="<...replacement tags...>"`